# Rendering HTML from a pipe

Tags: html, pipe

I would like to be able to generate HTML then pipe it to a program which will render it, something like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    for j in a b c
    do
        echo "<table border="1"><tr><td>$i</td><td>$j</td></tr></table>"
    done
done | /usr/bin/firefox
```

Unfortunately, firefox can't render data piped in from stdin. Neither can google-chrome. `lynx` can, but who wants to use that?

I tried creating a named pipe, opening that in chrome and/or firefox and then piping data to that -- but the browser didn't update when I sent data through the named pipe.

Are there any non text-based browsers which will render html from stdin? The output doesn't need to be glitzy, I'm mostly interested in making delimited data a little more readable, on the fly.

Edit:

I tried using bash's process substitution, e.g. `firefox <(sh /tmp/tablegen.sh)`, that didn't work either. Worst case scenario, I could output to a temp file, render, then delete, but I would prefer a slightly more elegant solution.

Comment: Similar question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24931/how-to-make-firefox-read-stdin

Comment: Good link; pretty well confirmed my suspicion that using a temp file is the only way to go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From one of the answers on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24931/how-to-make-firefox-read-stdin) I found [`bcat`](http://rtomayko.github.io/bcat/bcat.1.html):

```
NAME

  bcat - browser cat

DESCRIPTION

  The bcat utility reads from standard input, or one or
  more files, and pipes output into a web browser. file
  may be '-', in which case standard input is concatenated
  at that position.

  When invoked as btee, all input is written immediately
  to standard output in addition to being piped into
  the browser.
```

Now I can run a script like this:

```
$ python foo.py | bcat
```

**...and the resultant HTML output opens in a new Firefox tab!**

On Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linux distributions you can install `bcat` with this command:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ruby-bcat
```

Comment: Hi from 2019, the above install didn't work but `sudo gem install bcat` did. :-)